# Why is my function returning input1 and input2 as strings? I'm trying to create an addition function

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, sum, return

```
    def addition():
            int(input1)
            int(input2)
            mysum = input1 + input2
            print(mysum)


    input1: str = input("Enter integer #1 \n ")
    input2: str = input("Enter integer #2 \n ")
    addition()
```

I tried to convert the inputs to ints so that I could add them together but it just treats them like regularly doing:

print(text1("1") + text2("1")

result: 11

I also tried to use sum() with a "for numbers in input1 and input2" statement but produced the same result.

Comment: `int(input1)` converts the `input1` string to an integer, and then throws the result on the floor.  You must store the returned value somewhere.  Also, for good programming practice, you should pass those two values to the function, and not rely on globals.  Do `def addition(input1,input2):` and then call it with `addition(input1,input2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function to this

```
def addition():
      mysum = int(input1) + int(input2)
      print(mysum)
```

Answer (score 0):

The function should look like this:

```
def addition(number1, number2):
     print(int(number1) + int(number2))

input1 = input("Enter integer #1 \n ")
input2 = input("Enter integer #2 \n ")

addition(input1, input2)
```

Answer (score 0):

These lines:

```
        int(input1)
        int(input2)
```

Don't change the data type of the variables input1 and input2.

To save the change to the data type, you should use:

```
        input1=int(input1)
        input2=int(input2)
```